# Is there any recent study about percentage that computer spend on sorting?

Tags: reference-request, sorting

I came across this on Art of Computer Programming long time ago

> Computer manufacturers of the 1960s estimated that more than 25 percent 
>   of the running time on their computers was spent on sorting, when all their 
>   customers were taken into account.

Is there any recent study about the estimated percentage that computer spend on sorting? 1960s is pretty old.

Comment: [cs.SE] may not be the right place for this question. Practitioners have probably more insight into this.

Comment: I don't think this is a computer science question. If you were asking about the percentage of CPU cycles that were used playing video games, that would clearly not be computer science; I don't think sorting is any different in this respect.

Comment: it sounds like _applied_ CS to me & a reasonable question. but suspect the claim may be off. it could be that early database-like activities often amounted to sorting, which has now been replaced with database technology and anyway 25% sounds high. there is no attribution on the claim. DRs example doesnt really apply, sorting is a low level operation that is optimized via massive algorithmic study of different algorithms etc largely for reasons that its so fundamental. playing video games is an application. there are studies about how much time is spent doing [x] by databases etc...

Comment: Sorting is mostly a database operation these days. Databases are very very common, a database will only sort on insertions and updates (not on deletions of selects), so you're basically asking how much time do databases spend on upserts and on selects where no index is available.